# SQL Server: How to override Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server Import Wizard to import a 260GB flat text file into a table.  I have about 25 fields/columns per row and endless rows.  The large text file has vertical bars as a column delimiter and {CR}{LF} as a row delimiter.

My issue is this: some of the rows of data are not clean and missing a column delimiter or have an extra column delimiter.  Thus, data is getting pushed into the wrong fields.  This is problematic because each column has a very unique data type, thus creating the SQL Server data conversion failed error.

I don't mind incorrect data being pushed into the wrong fields - it seems to be happening for .01% of transactions and isn't a big issue.  So I would like to override this issue  and continue loading the data.  Right now the problem is SQL Server Import wizard stops all together when it hits this error, meaning I have to cleanse the data and to reload each time (very painful for such a large text file).

Any help/advice/suggestions on strategy here?

Thanks

Comment: Try loading all the fields as text, doing a manual conversion in the data flow. That way you can redirect any rows that fail conversion.

Comment: Pardon the ignorance, how does one do this?

Comment: Posting from phone, so can't supply a proper answer. Have a look here for error handling the data conversion data flow. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141679.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the primer Conan, but the article leaves out how to do manual conversion in SQL Server (import wizard or otherwise).  I've googled around to no avail.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the wizard,In the review data type mapping set the on error (global) to ignore

[image: Import Wizard setting]